# Authorization required RemoteSessionSettings Browserstack

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I am replacing `DesiredCapabilities` with `RemoteSessionSettings` but it seems that BrowserStack can't authenticate me.

How can I still use `RemoteSessionSettings` so that I can still perform parallel testing in BrowserStack?

Below is my sample code:

```
var capSettings = new RemoteSessionSettings();
capSettings.AddMetadataSetting("browserstack.user", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("user"));
capSettings.AddMetadataSetting("browserstack.key", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("key"));

capSettings.AddMetadataSetting("browser", "chrome");
capSettings.AddMetadataSetting("os", "Windows");
capSettings.AddMetadataSetting("os_version", "10");
capSettings.AddMetadataSetting("name", TestName);

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("server") + "/wd/hub/"), capSettings);
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `AddMetadataSetting` method puts the properties in the wrong part of the new session command payload for BrowserStack to work correctly. What you want is something like the following:

```
Dictionary<string, object> browserStackOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
browserStackOptions.Add("userName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("user"));
browserStackOptions.Add("accessKey", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("key"));

browserStackOptions.Add("os", "Windows");
browserStackOptions.Add("osVersion", "10");
browserStackOptions.Add("sessionName", TestName);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// N.B., the below line of code is specific to
// the 4.0 alpha of the .NET bindings. To
// use a 3.x version, use:
// options.AddAdditionalCapability("bstack:options", browserStackOptions, true);
options.AddAdditionalOption("bstack:options", browserStackOptions);

// If you truly need RemoteSessionSettings,
// you can do the following:
// RemoteSessionSettings settings = new RemoteSessionSettings(null, options);
// IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), settings);
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub/"), options);
```

The `RemoteSessionSettings` class is useful when the capabilities to be added are outside the main capabilities object, or if you are attempting to pass multiple browser-specific Options classes for potentially matching any one of multiple browsers for the session.

Comment: How can I pass multiple browser-specific and set to run parallel testing using `RemoteSessionSettings` in BrowserStack? Thank you.

Comment: Those are two different, unrelated things. The “multiple browser settings” case is useful when you’re saying, “I want to run this test against some browser, but I don’t care which one; however, if Chrome is selected, use _this_ set of options, and if Firefox is selected, use _that_ set of options.” Running tests in parallel is a function of your test runner, and entirely unrelated to the payload for the new session command.